# How can I get the action name in a Symfony2 controller?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, action

Is there a way to get the name of the action in a Symfony2 controller?

```
public function createAction(Request $request, $title) {

    // Expected result: create
    $name = $this->getActionName();

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use：

```
$request->attributes->get('_controller');
// will get yourBundle\Controller\yourController::CreateAction

$params = explode('::',$request->attributes->get('_controller'));
// $params[1] = 'createAction';

$actionName = substr($params[1],0,-6);
// $actionName = 'create';
```

Comment: This is also wrong. The action method needn't to be called *"somethingAction"* This can be fixed by adding a check on the name if "action" is tailing.

Comment: @Touki, as mentioned in my comment to my answer, the question is a Symfony2 question (see tag). Consider reading about the controller naming conventions here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#a-simple-controller

Comment: Even more, an action may not have a request placeholder in its function arguments declaration, then variable $request won't result accessible.

Comment: how can I get all actions inside controller?

Answer (score 3):

I found this snippet ([here](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/476)):

```
$matches    = array();
$controller = $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller');
preg_match('/(.*)\\\(.*)Bundle\\\Controller\\\(.*)Controller::(.*)Action/', $controller, $matches);
```

which seems to be a promising approach. <strike>This regexp actually doesn't work. But it won't be hard to fetch the action name by using `strstr()`.</strike> [Works!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22853480/1828051)

And returns ([see example](http://3v4l.org/Jr5X5))

```
Array
(
    [0] => Acme\MyBundle\Controller\MyController::myAction
    [1] => Acme
    [2] => My
    [3] => My
    [4] => my
)
```

If input was `Acme\MyBundle\Controller\MyController::myAction`.

Comment: Addition to my last sentence: Have a look at @leo's answer :)

Comment: No, this is wrong. A controller [can be defined as service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and therefor, needn't to be called *"SomethingController"*. The same thing goes for the action.

Comment: I don't get your point. I want to do something with the currently chosen action name (logging). No yes, that should by done via a Listener or Service. But I don't get you, why this is wrong? Can you precise?

Comment: What if the controller is `Acme\FooBundle\Controller\Foo::getBar`? Your regexp won't match

Comment: It's a SF2 convention to call you controller class `...Controller` and actions `...Action`. And I am only looking for these.

Comment: Then this is too localized. If someone is looking for a solution for this kind of matter, your answer won't help him

Comment: I insist. It's not too localized, because it's based on Symfony2 naming conventions!

Comment: I think it is valid, the regexp has just to be adapted for the project naming conventions you are using. If you are not using Action in all your controllers just remove it from the regexp.

Comment: Well... now you have two problems :D

Answer (score 1):

Now, I am using this with Symfony 2.8, (and Symfony3):

```
<?php

namespace Company\Bundle\AppBundle\Component\HttpFoundation;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as BaseRequest;

/**
 * Request shortcuts.
 */
class Request extends BaseRequest
{
    /**
     * Extract the action name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActionName()
    {
        $action = $this->get('_controller');
        $action = explode('::', $action);

        // use this line if you want to remove the trailing "Action" string
        //return isset($action[1]) ? preg_replace('/Action$/', '', $action[1]) : false;

        return $action[1];
    }

    /**
     * Extract the controller name (only for the master request).
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getControllerName()
    {
        $controller = $this->get('_controller');
        $controller = explode('::', $controller);
        $controller = explode('\\', $controller[0]);

        // use this line if you want to remove the trailing "Controller" string
        //return isset($controller[4]) ? preg_replace('/Controller$/', '', $controller[4]) : false;

        return isset($controller[4]) ? $controller[4] : false;
    }
}
```

To use this custom request class, you must "use" it in your `web/app*.php` controllers:

```
use Company\Bundle\AppBundle\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// ...
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
// ...
```

Then in your controller:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home_page")
     * @Template("")
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function homePageAction(Request $request)
    {
        $controllerName = $request->getControllerName();
        $actionName = $request->getActionName();

        dump($controllerName, $actionName); die();

        // ...
    }
```

Will output:

```
AppController.php on line 27:
"AppController"
AppController.php on line 27:
"homePageAction"
```

You can also access these functions through the `RequestStack` service:

```
class MyService
{
    /**
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function myService()
    {
        $this->controllerName = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getControllerName();
        $this->actionName = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getActionName();

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: how can I get all actions inside controller?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Controller as a Service than the schema is different:

`$request->attributes->get('_controller');` will return "service_id:createAction"

A possible solution for both schemas:

```
$controller = $request->attributes->get('_controller');
$controller = str_replace('::', ':', $controller);
list($controller, $action) = explode(':', $controller);
```

Answer (score 0):

In all version of symfony and without $request or container, service or nothing else... , directly in your method

```php
public function myMethod(){
   $methodName = __METHOD__;
   return $methodName;
}

// return App\Controller\DefaultController::myMethod

public function mySecondMethod(){
   $methodName = explode('::', __METHOD__);
   return $methodName[1];
}

// return mySecondMethod
```