# Stuck with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Coming from another answer, I am stuck with a regexp (what are the odds...?).

```
$matches    = array();
// $controller = $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller');
$controller = "Acme\MyBundle\Controller\MyController::myAction";
preg_match('/(.*)\\\Bundle\\\(.*)\\\Controller\\\(.*)Controller::(.*)Action/', $controller, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Returns ([see example](http://3v4l.org/nfiIe))

```
Array
(
)
```

Expected result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Acme\MyBundle\Controller\MyController::myAction
    [1] => Acme
    [2] => My
    [3] => My
    [4] => my
)
```

Anyone can help? This regexp seems to be legit, maybe it's just a problem with the backslashes? I tried around but didn't get it.

Comment: What are you trying to match ?

Comment: It doesn't match `\MyBundle\ ` part, since you only have `\Bundle\ ` in your regex.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran uh yeah sorry, forgot to detail that, will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below expression. Is it expected? Or tell me your exact requirements.

```
<?php

$matches    = array();
// $controller = $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller');
$controller = "Acme\MyBundle\Controller\MyController::myAction";
preg_match('/(.*)\\\(.*)Bundle\\\Controller\\\(.*)Controller::(.*)Action/', $controller, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```