# Get 'action' property of a Symfony2 form in controller

Tags: forms, symfony

I'd like to extract the action of a Symfony2 form in my controller. `$form->getConfig()->getAction()` just returns an empty string.

Is there any other way?

```
public function fooAction(Request $request)
{
    $bar = new BarEntity();
    $form = $this->createForm(new BarType(), $bar);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $action = ''; // how to get the action?

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
 }
```

**Example:**

```
 <form action="this/is/the/value/im/interested/in" enctype="...">...</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the action name in a Symfony2 controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852664/how-can-i-get-the-action-name-in-a-symfony2-controller)

Comment: @sebbo I apologize for my unclear question. I'm actually interested in the *action* value of the rendered `<form></form>`

Comment: $form->getConfig()->getAction(); will work if you have set the action.  There is no action by default.  You build it in the template or you set it when building the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action is empty, because if action is not explicitly specified in form builder, Symfony form builder use HTML form default behavior. Default HTML form behavior on submit when action is empty or not set is that form is send to current URL.

So if you want get URL of that action you need use some logic:

```
$action = $form->getConfig()->getAction();
if(empty($action) === true) {
     $action = $this->get('request')->getRequestUri();
}
```