# Symfony2: How to get action name in form class

Tags: php, forms, symfony

My form is on the base of self-referenced entity (category have parent category)

For the `parent` field, I want to have different `query_builder` function depending of action name. When action is `update`, `parent` field (drop-down list) contains all categories, excepting edited category. This is work good. But, when action is `Create new`, parent form field contains only `null` value (in my case Main category).
This is category form class
`CategoryType` class:

```
namespace Dimas\CatalogBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Parent Category ',
                'empty_value' => '- Main level -',
                'class' => 'DimasCatalogBundle:Category', 'property' => 'getTreeName',
                'required' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
                    //need only if action is 'update'
                    $er->where('u.id <> :selfId');
                    $er->setParameter(':selfId', $options['data']->getId());
                    // end if
                    return $er;
                },
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Dimas\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'dimas_catalogbundle_category';
    }

}
```

Is it a good idea to add `if` in `query_builder`? How to get action name?
`$options` array contains action name, but it is so deep inside.

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852664/how-can-i-get-the-action-name-in-a-symfony2-controller      you need to get is from the request

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try to send action name from controller to the form.

Comment: @psyhos write your result as an answer, it will be better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pass in an option into the builder from your controller action that can act as a conditional:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if ($options['action'] === 'update') {
        $callable = function (EntityRepository $er)...
    } elseif ($option['action'] === 'Create new') {
        $callable = function (EntityRepository $er) ...
    }

    ...
        'required' => false,
        'query_builder' => $callable,
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Dimas\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category'
        ))
        ->setRequired(['action'])
    ;
}

// Your controller

public function createNewAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(), $category, ['action' => 'Create new']);
}

public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(), $category, ['action' => 'update']);
}
```

Comment: In my controller I alredy use `action ` : `$form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('category_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        )); `

Answer (score -1):

**I achieve result this way:**
I use `EventListener` to my form class. Learned from [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class)
Now my `builForm` function in `CategoryType` class looks like that:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('name');

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, 
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
        $category = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // check if the Category object is "new"
        // If no data is passed to the form, the data is "null".
        // This should be considered a new "Category"
        if (!$category || null === $category->getId()) {
            $form->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Parent Category ',
                'empty_value' => '- Main level -',
                'class' => 'DimasCatalogBundle:Category', 'property' => 'getTreeName',
                'required' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
               },
            ));
        } else {
                $form->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                    'label' => 'Parent Category ',
                    'empty_value' => '- Main level -',
                    'class' => 'DimasCatalogBundle:Category', 'property' => 'getTreeName',
                    'required' => false,
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->where('u.id <> :selfId')
                            ->setParameter(':selfId', $options['data']->getId());
                    },
                ));
            }
        });
    }
```

I did not get action (but I still wont).